# Winrt bluetooth error

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing universal application for Windows 8.1. My application works with bluetooth device, phone works perfectly, but on the tablet I have error while connecting to device:

> The requested address is not valid in its context (0x80072741)

here my code:

```
        await
            streamSocket.ConnectAsync(
                new HostName(info.Id),
                "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}");
        dataReader = new DataReader(streamSocket.InputStream);
        dataWriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
```

Capabilities:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's RT, you're not alone !

Please go to post # 357 : https://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/8077/windows-phone-8-pebble-app/p5 .. I think it'll help !

Comment: if I understand you correctly, it is recommended to use RfcommDeviceService. But in this service there are some bugs. That's why I using StreamSockets. After I used it, all bugs on WIndowsPhone was fixed

Comment: If it will be useful for you, this code works perfectly on windows 10. That's why we decided to stop supporting windows 8.1 tablets